# Cannot read ajax post data sent to server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Here is my problem, might be a silly problem but I really do not see what is wrong.

In laravel, ajax post request is made and data is sent to the server (since it is shown in network tab of the browser).

But on the server side, as I the request is fetched, non of the data can be accessed (seems like they are not even included is the request).

The ajax request is within another post request on success (if it matters).

**Request**

```
var projectid='21';
var data = [{'project' : projectid, 'fileName' : response.fileName}];
json = JSON.stringify (data);
console.log(json);
$.ajax({
        method :'POST',
        url:'/mtdir',
        data: json,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        contentType: false,
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                  }

    });
```

**Controller**

```
public function mtdir(Request $request) {

    dd($request);

    //$ProjectID=$request->input('ProjectID');
    //$ProjectID=$_GET['ProjectID'];
    $fileName = $request->get("fileName");
    $fileName = $_REQUEST ["fileName"];

}
```

I already tried to format my data with JSON.stringify

```
 data = {'project' : projectid, 'fileName' : response.fileName}
```

or

```
 data = [{'project' : projectid, 'fileName' : response.fileName}]
```

If only sent as an object {'project' : projectid, 'fileName' : response.fileName}, browser network tab only fetches [object Object].

Thanks for help ! :)

Comment: Try to send the CSRF token in the request body as `_csrf` instead of the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing the

```
processData:false,
contentType: false,
```

in your ajax request.
you can check if something is wrong with the inputs by doing

```
var_dump("php://input");
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like processData:false, contentType: false, were causing my problem. I did not even think about removing them because it usually works with that. Any idea why ?

Comment: Usually you use them when using formData (best solution for file upload).